# Same blog, one theme for each category

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, themes

I'm coding a blog for a side project in Codeigniter. There will be three modules in my blog.

What I need to know how to do, for example:

- example.org -> show all posts with module3 theme
- example.org/module1 -> shows only posts of module1 with module1 theme
- example.org/module2 -> shows only posts of module2 with module2 theme
- example.org/module3 -> shows only posts of module3 with module3 theme

Any thoughts how to deal with this in the URL schema? (Routing)

Comment: Can't you just render a different view based on the controller (module1, module2, etc.)?

Comment: But i want to use the same controller. Just the post controller.

Comment: Easily possible. Question is, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple switching:

```
class Post extends CI_Controller{

function index($module = null)
{
   switch($module)
   {
      case NULL:
      case 'module3':
        //load theme 3
      break;
      case 'module1':
        //load theme 1
      break;
      case 'module2':
        //load theme 2
      break;     
  }

}
```

In your routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "post";
$route['(:any)'] = "post/index/$1";
```

How to implement not-existing cases is up to you now, this is just a start. Also, the ":any" route is a catch-all that will grab *any* url, so you'll need to exclude (by placing them *before* any other routes you want to remap. Or you could take a look at the [_remap()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html) function to use in your controller

Comment: Come on damien, you should have waited a little. I wanted to see him trying a little.;-)

Comment: I know, I agree with you, but I felt 10 minutes of rush before stopping asnwering for another month or two. Bear with me...

Comment: Im dealing with the routes now... Storing a session var with the module i get from url! Tkz all

Answer (score 0):

You can modify core of CI, but I think you better use RewriteRule.